# JQuery - AutoComplete window width

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Can I set JQuery AutoComplete selection window's width greater than the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the width in "open" callback function

```
$("#searchText").autocomplete({
     source: "url"
     open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css({
            'width' :   '443px'
        });
     }
});
```